# Is there a way to plot line with start and end coordinate?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have this table and I would like to plot the start and end coordinate of petals and leaves (one color for petls and another for leaves).

| string | id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| petals | id | 50 | 100 |
| leaves | id | 101 | 151 |
| petals | id | 152 | 202 |
| leaves | id | 203 | 253 |
| petals | id | 254 | 305 |
| leaves | id | 306 | 356 |

I don't want represent it with a dot but with a line starting from the start coordinate and ending at the end coordinate for petals and leaves represented with different color.

Is there any way?

Comment: Yes, with the {ggplot2} package you'd be using `geom_segment()`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use it. The problem is that I don't have Y axis coordinates, although I could use the value 1 in this case and have everything at height 1. The problem is that I don't track the different segments when I put x = start and xend = end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could have something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y = string, x = start, colour = string)) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = string, xend = end), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellowgreen", "violet")) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_fixed(20) +
  labs(x = "Position")
```

[image]

If you want the lines at the same height you could do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = 1, x = start, colour = string)) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = 1, xend = end), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellowgreen", "violet")) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_fixed(500) +
  labs(x = "Position") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "mm"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(string = c("petals", "leaves", "petals", "leaves", 
"petals", "leaves"), id = c("id", "id", "id", "id", "id", "id"
), start = c(50L, 101L, 152L, 203L, 254L, 306L), end = c(100L, 
151L, 202L, 253L, 305L, 356L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Something like this may be fine but how would you set it if the dataframe was much larger and you couldn't manually type "petals", "leaves" and "id". The same from the coordinates.

Comment: And also, how would you go about having the lines at the same height?

Comment: @LucaCorda you wouldn't need to type petals and leaves lots of time. This is just the reproducible version of the data you posted in tabular format, so people can get your example data frame by just copying and pasting the code above. It was generated using the `dput` function, which is the best way to share reproducible data here. If you want the lines at the same height, I will show an alternative in my answer.

Comment: @LucaCorda see my update. Just to reiterate, `df` in the code above is just a stand in for whatever your data frame is called, and you can ignore the "Data" section I have included in the answer. So instead of `ggplot(df, ` you would use `ggplot(my_table` or whatever your data frame is called. Does that make sense?

Comment: it's perfect and it works and thank you very much. The problem remains that my data.frame is too big so I end up creating a chart where you don't see anything. Do you have any idea how I could make it visible perhaps by making it smaller? I have a dataframe like this with 2,000 rows.

Comment: @LucaCorda it will be very difficult for anyone looking at a plot like that to discern any details. Often with that density of data you need to summarise it in some way. Can you tell me what the actual data represents and what the purpose of the plot is?

Comment: Thank you Allan. I'm working on DNA sequences. Let's say for example that petals and leaves are the names of my sequence. The id, that is always the same is the id of the read. What I want to do is to represent the pattern of these sequences (petals and leaves with they own coordinates) within the read  (in my case i have a table with about two thousand rows and four columns: string, id, start and end).

Comment: When I tried to represent the pattern with you code I'm not able to see nothing because the read is very long and therefore it is impossible to represent the pattern in this way. Do you have any idea how can i do it? Maybe representing the sequences (let's call them strings) with a dot rather than a line? Or maybe just zooming in on a piece of read? In any case I would like to show the pattern, the alternation of petals and leaves inside this read and also show the distance between them which is kept constant throughout the read.

Comment: @LucaCorda A good modern pc monitor is typically less than 2000 pixels across. There is no way to show over 2000 data points in a single line - even if you only had 1 pixel per data point your screen would not be big enough to show the data in the way you describe, and no-one would be able to see any details. You really just need to think of a different way to show your data.

Comment: What if, instead of making horizontal lines, they were done vertically?